# jquery in RWD on load and resize multiple execute

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

My attempt is to toggle a headers siblings based on if the window size is below 767. This is a responsive design so i put a bind on the load and resize events. However, i am getting multiple firings when i click on my header.

```
jQuery(window).bind('load resize', function($) {

  if( jQuery(window).width() < 767) {

    jQuery('footer h2').siblings().hide();          
    jQuery('footer h2').on('click', function() {                            
        jQuery(this).siblings().slideToggle();
});

  } else {
     jQuery('footer h2').unbind('click');
     jQuery('footer h2').siblings().show(); 
  }                             
});
```

basically the image rolls down and than up.

Comment: You say you are using RWD, so why are you using jQuery for this? Add a media breakpoint at 767px and style the appropriate elements with `display:none`

Comment: still new to RWD. sometimes i just think 'hey js can just do it' because i've done it that way in the past. do you have any good examples of this i can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one issue could be that you're binding a click handler every time the window is resized (if the new width < 767). So if you are already less than 767 and you resize to another width that is less than 767, you'll have multiple click handlers bound.

Comment: so i just unbind any click events to that selector `jQuery('footer h2').unbind('click');` this seems to have solved my issue. however, is this the right thing to do? this was inserted before the `if` statement thus removing unbind in the `else`